# get all imdb id from page url by preg_match_all

Tags: php, curl

How can I get all IMDB ids from a page? For example, I want get all ids from [here](http://www.imdb.com/movies-coming-soon/). In that page, urls are of the format:

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0948470/
```

I need to get all ids from page using `preg_match_all()` - can any help me?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your questions - use Markdown to make it as readable as possible, and use an English spell-checker if you can (in Firefox this is offered on edit boxes as standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm giving cooked-up code, but I also explain it:

1. Obtain the HTML source
2. Parse all `<a>` `href` attributes
3. Test with a regular expression if their value matches.
4. If it matches, extract the id from the link and store it in a way that you don't get any duplicates.
5. Done.

Example/[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/I88jcr)

```
// initialize
$ids   = array(); 
$url   = 'http://www.imdb.com/movies-coming-soon/'; # this URL
$expr  = '//a/@href';                               # these attributes
$regex = '(/title/(tt\d{5,7})/)u';                  # matching this regex
$match = 1;                                         # take group 1

// process
foreach((new DOMXpath(@DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($url)))->query($expr) as $obj)
    preg_match($regex, $obj->value, $matches)
      && $ids[$matches[$match]] = 0;
    ;
$ids = array_keys($ids);

// output
print_r($ids);
```

(*Notes:* You tagged this question PHP5, current stable PHP5 is 5.4, so is this example; If you configure your PHP5 version with the curl wrappers, this code is `curl`.)

**Edit:** Lower PHP Versions:

```
...
// process
$xp = new DOMXpath(@DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($url));
foreach($xp->query($expr) as $obj)
...
```

**Edit2:** Just seeing that IMDB tags it's markup, so it's possible to retrieve the actual movie entries of that list rather than any title links on that page.

This require a little improvement in the xpath expression used. Because the parsing is now much more intelligent, duplicates do not exist and so there is no need to remove them:

```
// initialize
$ids   = array();
$url   = 'http://www.imdb.com/movies-coming-soon/'; # this URL
$expr  = '//*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie"]
                //a[@itemprop="url"]/@href';        # these attributes
$regex = '(/title/(tt\d{5,7})/)u';                  # matching this regex
$match = 1;                                         # take group 1

// process
$xp = new DOMXpath(@DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($url));
foreach($xp->query($expr) as $obj)
    preg_match($regex, $obj->value, $matches)
        && $ids[] = $matches[$match];
;
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR online 12 
i think my php version not supported

Comment: @M Sona: Which one you have? Anyway, made an edit, should do it unless you're using some very old PHP version which I doubt.

Comment: @M Sona: I improved it again, was just seeing that IMDB uses microformats that help a lot in parsing the website.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I am not giving a cooked-up code. A simple function of "View selection source" in Firefox lets me have a look that each link has href property in format:

```
href="/title/tt1615065/"
```

Now it shall be trivial to build a RegEx. I suggest you a good [RegEx tutorial](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm) and a non-Greedy match will do the job. Good luck!